# What is -D in maven command like -DgroupId or -DartifactId

Tags: java, maven

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

Why do we append -D to every parameter for e.g. -DgroupId or -DartifactId . What does it denotes ?

Comment: add your codes please.

Answer (score 1):

The D in -D type options most probably have their origin in C/C++ compilers which used a similar syntax to define preprocessor macros from CLI. It stands for "Define". 
I do not have an exact documentation and source to verify this, though.

Comment: Thanks Chetan this was helpful !!